# SFMC MobilePUSH SDK error setKeychainAccessibleAttribute

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, sdk

I implement mobile application which plug with SFMC SDK, according to SF guild from this link sf ref: https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/blob/v8.0.10/LearningApp/LearningApp/AppDelegate.swift

After implemented, the application is popping up the window asking for user to enter password, after a while, the app is crashed.

My team found out that the root cause is from this line of code (line 63 in the link above) // To override the Keycahin accessibility attribute SFMCSdk.setKeychainAccessibleAttribute(accessibleAttribute: kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly)

My question is that, if I decided to cut this line of code out, will there be any other effects on the app? or can anyone explain what does this line of code actually does ?

Answer (score 0):

SFMCSdk.setKeychainAccessibleAttribute(accessibleAttribute: kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly)

The above line is just to tell how accessibility attribute can be overridden by the consuming application. SDK by default sets it to "kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly".

There is no harm in removing the line mentioned. However, if you have have the data protection set to "NSFileProtectionComplete", the below code is should be added if you don't want to consider the keychain exceptions as fatal exceptions.

```
 SFMCSdk.setKeychainAccessErrorsAreFatal(errorsAreFatal: false)
```

Thanks,
Prakashini